# Change in datetimetime in, due to difference in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I would like to obtain the rate of change in time for the sample data below:

```
datetime        | value 
2020-03-01:00   | 20
2020-03-02:01   | 21
2020-03-03:02   | 19.3
2020-03-04:03   | 22
2020-03-05:04   | 23.7
2020-03-06:05   | 30
```

Sample answer should create a new column called change in time. This column should be updated when the "value" column is above a particular range say 20.

Sample answer is as below:

```
datetime        | value  | change in time
2020-03-01:00   | 20     |   -
2020-03-02:01   | 21     |  1mins
2020-03-03:02   | 19.3   |  0mins
2020-03-04:03   | 22     |  1mins
2020-03-05:04   | 23.7   |  1mins
2020-03-06:05   | 30     |  1mins
```

Comment: how come there is 0 min time difference?

Comment: Year-Month-day-hour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) wth convert to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and then replace to `0` if values bellow `20`, last divide by `60` for minutes:

```
#change format by data, here is used YYYY-MM-DD:HH
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d:%H')
    

df['change in time'] = (df['datetime'].diff()
                                      .dt.total_seconds()
                                      .mask(df['value'].lt(20), 0)
                                      .div(60))
```